# Как установить правильную версию пакета bower-asset/tinymce?

Tags: composer, tinymce

Есть проект на yii2, в нем ряд зависимостей, в частности

```
"require": {
    ...
    "bower-asset/tinymce": ">=4.7.4,<5.0",
    ...
}
```

в composer-lock версия указана 4.7.4
но, когда устанавливаю через composer install, 
в процессе установки загружается версия 4.7.4, а по факту в коде версия 5.0.1

кеш почистила, есть fxp/composer-asset-plugin v1.4.0

В чем может быть проблема, как можно исправить?

Comment: дополните ваш вопрос результатом команд: 1) `composer depends  -- bower-asset/tinymce` - посмотреть какие пакеты имеют зависимость от bower-asset/tinymce, c указанием требуемых версий. 2) `composer show -- bower-asset/tinymce` - посмотреть установленную версию пакета.

Comment: проблема в итоге решилась удалением и установкой: composer remove package, composer require package